# Powershell DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry -> setting the "msExchHideFromAddressLists" property

Tags: powershell

I just don't believe how many problems I'm running into, once I fix one thing, something else seems to pop up.

Ok, I have now realized how to set properties in a seperate domain with credentials, hence:

```
$user_gde = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://CN=user,OU=somewhere,DC=company,DC=local","username","password")
```

This is fine for changeing the following property:

```
$user_gde.PSBase.MoveTo($dest)
```

Works like a charm. However when I wish to set the MSExchHideFromAddressLists property. It just does not work.

```
$user_gde.msExchHideFromAddressLists = $True
```

Does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user_gde.psbase.InvokeSet('msExchHideFromAddressLists',$true)
$user_gde.SetInfo()
```